# Visualize regular grid as TMS

Tags: tilemill, visualisation, tile-map-service, grids-graticules, tilestache

I have a regular grid of points with wind values with a distance between the points of approx. 300 m. I would like to visualize this and get a TMS (with TileStache) as a regular grid of arrows (direction + strength as size or colour) for every zoom level.

I expect it to look something like this:

[image: Wind Grid]

*Grid of wind arrows*

or like this from [WXTiles](http://www.wxtiles.com/)

I tried to get something similar with TileMill but the results are not convincing as you can see on the images:

[image: Wind with markers]

*TileMill and Markers*

[image: Wind with shields]

*TileMill and Shields*

What would be a way to get a regular grid of arrows in every zoom level? Do I have to prepare a separate file of points for every zoom level with different point intervals? Do you have any suggestions? If possible that would work with TileStache.

Comment: Personally, I find your first example with markers pretty convincing--or at least a great start ( : .  Where are you getting your data?

Comment: @JamesConkling the first example is prerendered and not suitable for a TMS. For the TMS I have a database with point data. Originaly the data is from noaa and interpolated by our company.

Comment: But presumably if you can pre-render it, you can render it on the fly with TileStache, yes?

Comment: I can't tell if you are having issues cartographic design (in which case, what's the issue: too many markers in the first example, or markers getting clipped in the second, or markers not appearing in a perfect grid, or something else), *or* issues with functionality.

Comment: The issues are of cartographic design: I have a lot of points - too many for small zoom levels - and I want them automatically appear in a perfect grid with a certain grid spacing in every zoom level. Like here: http://www.wxtiles.com/

Comment: OK, I was just messing around with some dummy gridded point data on my machine.  I had thought there was a way to add padding around each marker or shield, but couldn't find a way to hack it--will return to it if I have any other thoughts, because it seems like it should be pretty straightforward.

Comment: I expected to find a padding parameter for markers or shields but didn't.  So I guess you'd have to manipulate the data on the server side: have the server output point grids at different cell widths, and load those different layers at specified zoom levels.

Comment: There is shield-min-distance and I tried it with different settings but did not get a regular grid. I guess I will try to get grids with different cell widths for the zoom levels as you suggested. Thanks for your help